# Why audioElement.currentTime is always set to 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a music player and to make a play pause button work , I am trying to execute the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="brand"><img src="./others/logo.png" alt="Spotify">Spotify</li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="songList">
            <h1>Best of NCS</h1>
            <div class="songItemContainer">
                <div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img alt="1" >
                        <span class = "songName"></span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "0" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img alt="2" >
                        <span class = "songName"></span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "1" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img alt="3" >
                        <span class = "songName"></span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "2" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img alt="4" >
                        <span class = "songName"></span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "3" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img   alt="5" >
                        <span class = "songName"></span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "4" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img alt="6" >
                        <span class = "songName">r</span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "5" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="songItem">
                        <img alt="7" height="44px" width="44px" >
                        <span class = "songName"></span>
                        <span class="songlistplay"><span class="timeStamp">05:34</span><i id = "6" class="songItemPlay fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="songBanner"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="bottom">
        <input type="range" name="range" id="myProgressBar" min ='0' max = "100" value="0">
        <div class="icons">
            <!-- fontawesome icons  -->
            <i class="fa-solid fa-3x fa-backward-step" id="previous"></i>      
            <i class="fa-regular fa-3x fa-circle-play" id="masterPlay"></i>    
            <i class="fa-solid fa-3x fa-forward-step" id="next"></i>      
        </div>
        <div   class="songInfo">
            <img src="./others/playing.gif" id="gif" alt="">  <p id="songInfo"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d76649665f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: antiquewhite;

}

nav{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    height: 9vh;    
    background-color:black ;
    color: white;
}

nav ul li{
    padding-left: 3vw;
}

.brand{
    padding-left: 1vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.brand img {
    width: 3vw;
    height: 5vh;
}

.container{
    min-height: 71vh;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    margin: 3vh auto;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 70%;
    background-image: url(./others/uwp2726170.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.bottom{
    position: sticky;
    height: 14vh;
    background-color: black;
    bottom:0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.icons{
    margin-top:1.5vh ;
}

.icons i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#myProgressBar{
    width: 80vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.songItem{
    display: flex;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 25vw;
    margin: 1.5vh 2vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border-color: whitesmoke;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-radius: 34px;
    border-width:0.2px ;
}

.songItem:hover{
    background-color: #e2a3e8;
    color: black;
}

.songItem img{
    width: 3vw;
    border-radius: 26px;
}

.timeStamp{
    margin: 0 0.5vw
}

.songList{
    padding: 2vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.songlistplay i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.songItemContainer{
    margin-top: 8vh;
}

.songInfo{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    left: 10vw;
}

.songInfo img{
    width: 3vw;
}

.songInfo img{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in;
}
```

JS:

```
console.log("Welcome to Spotify ! ")

// Initialize the variables 

let songIndex =0;
let masterPlay = document.getElementById('masterPlay')
let myProgressBar = document.getElementById('myProgressBar')
let gif = document.getElementById('gif')
let songItems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItem'))
let songInfo = document.getElementById('songInfo')
let songs =[
    {songName: "GOAT", filePath: "./songs/GOAT.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover1.jpg"},
    {songName: "Alone", filePath: "./songs/Alone.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover2.jpg"},
    {songName: "Homicide", filePath: "./songs/Homicide.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover3.jpg"},
    {songName: "Satisfy", filePath: "./songs/Satisfy.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover4.jpg"},
    {songName: "Levels", filePath: "./songs/Levels.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover5.jpeg"},
    {songName: "Game Over", filePath: "./songs/GameOver.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover6.jpg"},
    {songName: "OG", filePath: "./songs/OG.mp3",coverPath: "./covers/cover7.png"},
];
let audioElement = new Audio(songs[0].filePath);
songInfo.innerText = songs[0].songName


songItems.forEach((element,i)=>{
    element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = songs[i].coverPath
    element.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText= songs[i].songName
})





// Listen to events 

audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate',()=>{
    
    // Update seekbar 
    progress = parseInt((audioElement.currentTime/audioElement.duration)*100)
    myProgressBar.value = progress
    
})

myProgressBar.addEventListener('change',()=>{
    audioElement.currentTime = (myProgressBar.value * audioElement.duration)/100
})

const makeAllPlays = ()=>{
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
        element.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
        element.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
    })
}



Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        songIndex = parseInt(e.target.id)
        makeAllPlays()
        // e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
        // e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
        songInfo.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName
        audioElement.src = songs[songIndex].filePath
        
        if (audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime<=0){
            audioElement.play();
            masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
            masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
            e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-play')
            e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-pause')
            gif.style.opacity = 1
            console.log(parseInt(audioElement.currentTime))
            
            
        }
        else{
            audioElement.pause();
            console.log("hii")
            masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
            masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-play")
            gif.style.opacity = 0
            e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause')
            e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-play')
            
        }
        
        
        
        // audioElement.play()
        // audioElement.currentTime=0
        // masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        // masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
        // gif.style.opacity = 1
    })
})
// audioElement.play()

masterPlay.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    if (audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime<=0){
        audioElement.play();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        songItemPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        songItemPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
        gif.style.opacity = 1
        
    }
    else{
        audioElement.pause();
        masterPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
        masterPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-play")
        gif.style.opacity = 0
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        songItemPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
        songItemPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-play")
        
    }
})

document.getElementById('previous').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(songIndex===0){
        songIndex=0
    }
    else{
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        songItemPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
        songItemPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-play")
        songIndex -=1
    }
    songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
    songItemPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    songItemPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
    songInfo.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName
    audioElement.src = songs[songIndex].filePath
    audioElement.play()
    audioElement.currentTime=0
})
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if(songIndex>=6){
        songIndex=0
    }
    else{
        songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
        songItemPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
        songItemPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-play")
        songIndex +=1
    }
    songItemPlay = document.getElementById(songIndex)
    songItemPlay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    songItemPlay.classList.add("fa-circle-pause")
    songInfo.innerText = songs[songIndex].songName
    audioElement.src = songs[songIndex].filePath
    audioElement.play()
    audioElement.currentTime=0
})
```

The code to play music (under the if statement) is working , while the code(under the else statement) to pause music is not working. I think it is not working because audioElement.currentTime is always set to 0 . What's the solution ? please help me

Comment: I think you must store current time in local storage.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).